# Postgres OVERLAPS date function in TypeORM

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I want to transfer the query to TypeORM.

It looks like this in Postgres

```
SELECT * 
from equipment_charging 
where (equipment_charging."start_date"::date, equipment_charging."end_date"::date) OVERLAPS (DATE '2020-09-10', DATE '2020-09-14')
```

I'm writing this query in TypeORM like this:

```
.where(
  '(equipment_charging.startDate::date, equipment_charging.endDate::date) OVERLAPS (DATE :startDate, DATE :endDate)',
  { startDate, endDate },
)
```

it gives me error like this:

```
{"context":"ExceptionsHandler","stack":["QueryFailedError: syntax error at or near \"$1\"\n    at new QueryFailedError
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know TypeORM but try to remove the `DATE` keyword in front of the parameters. It's only needed for typed constant values, but if `startDate` or `endDate` are already `DATE` instances, they are not needed

Comment: thanks a lot, unfortunately it did not work… it says "syntax error at or near \",\"" don't get which comma this is :(

Answer (score 0):

If equipment_charging.startDate and equipment_charging.endDate are already date type in database I think that you could remove `::date`

In same idea try to give directly date type for the input.

I also use lot of double quote for query builder in typeorm
try this:

```
.where(
  '("equipment_charging"."startDate", "equipment_charging"."endDate") OVERLAPS (:startDate, :endDate)',
  { startDate, endDate },
)
```

And convert startDate and endDate to date if needed (with parseIso of date fns for example)